# Typescript: How to specify algorithms on generic interface, so that they are usable on derived generic classes?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

Consider the (simplified) code:

```
interface GenericInterface<T> { value: T }

function genericIdentity<T>(instance : GenericInterface<T>) : GenericInterface<T> {
    return instance;
}

class GenericImplementingClass<T> implements GenericInterface<T> {
    value!: T 
    add() {}
}

let numberInstance = new GenericImplementingClass<number>();
let genericInstance = genericIdentity(numberInstance);
genericInstance.add(); // ERROR: Property 'add' does not exist on type 'GenericInterface<unknown>'.
```

How can I write the function `genericIdentity` in a way, that it returns the derived type including the template parameter?

My attempts:

```
// trying to decouple the types for derivation and the template type
// ERROR: '?' expected at the ")" - which doesn't make much sense to me   
function genericIdentity<T, DerivedInterface>(instance : DerivedInterface extends GenericInterface<T>) : DerivedInterface {
    return instance;
}

// trying to specify, that the type extends the interface
// - VS-Code goes completely bonkers with error messages
function genericIdentity<DerivedInterface<T> extends GenericInterface<T>>(instance : DerivedInterface<T>) : DerivedInterface<T> {
    return instance;
}
```

(In actuality I have this issue with a TreeWalker function that is defined on a generic tree interface, and I would like it to return `Tree<T>` instead of `TreeInterface<T>`)

Comment: `GenericInterface<T>` is *too* simplified to be an example of anything; unused type parameters don't behave how you want, see the [generics faq entries](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#generics) and please [edit] the code to use the `T` type parameter structurally inside `GenericInterface<T>`.

Comment: Your function says it returns a `GenericInterface`. You should really be saying that `T extends GenericInterface<any>`, and then return that `T`. https://tsplay.dev/WPgxzm

Comment: @vr. Amazing, that was exactly what I needed. Would you like to promote your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Also: is there maybe a benefit in writing this more explicitly as `genericIdentity<T, DerivedInterface extends GenericInterface<T>>` instead, or is this just unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: The only reason why I would write it like that is if I need to use `T` elsewhere in the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is currently written, your function returns a `GenericInterface`. Instead, you should make `T` the generic interface itself. Then, you can return `T` directly. TypeScript will be smart enough to infer the type parameter for the given generic interface.

```
function genericIdentity<T extends GenericInterface<any>>(instance: T): T {
    return instance;
}
```

Now, your example code works:

```
let numberInstance = new GenericImplementingClass<number>();
let genericInstance = genericIdentity(numberInstance);
//  ^? GenericImplementingClass<number>
genericInstance.add(); // okay
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIRNYCCS5rxIA8AKgHzIDeAUMncgG5wA2ArhAFzIkDc1AvtWoxWIBGGAB7EMgDmGLLgAmGCWACepZBAAekEEoDOaBVGx5IsRBCJwQ6smQAUoQ2DtIuJAJReqteigIMFYoGVd3MQg+QWoEZjhDY3RMM1wAWwAHZgh01VBZAGEEpNIKYCycvPBk03N8K2Jyf3pGFnYAQi8+ALo4JSUnbypBWJywZBBWdIAjaDw3DxQAXkmIAHcTVPNK3PyQIpLDIinZ6GdvPnG5OtwQRajkVflt5XyNJ1O5qAXIpEvqC9FL8lgA6fqDAFAA)

Comment: I know this is not part of the question, but is it possible to extend this in a way, that the template type of the generic is automatically deducible? Using your other comment as a base I tried this:
`function extractValue<T, DerivedInstance extends GenericInterface<T>>(instance : DerivedInstance) : T {
    return instance.value;
}`, but applying it leaves the template value "unknown"